dyld[77786]: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../../opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.73.dylib
After change php version from 8.0 to 8.3 i am getting this error, when i try to check php version by using
php -v



Fix the path! It literally says "no such file" in the message...

unable to go on this path

because it doesn't exist... you need to rectify this.
